# Samsung Galaxy S4 Not Displaying Push Notifications from Parse.com

Tags: android, parse-platform

We're about to launch a new app on iOS & Android, using Parse.com to provide the push notification service.

We've been testing on 5 devices internally: iPhone, iPad, Galaxy Tab, Galaxy S3, Galaxy S4

Here is an example of one of the pushes:

```
{ "deal_id": "ad60b089-6678-42d9-a503-3525d0c8c065", "alert": "Reliable Rentals has a new deal available. Check your favourites now!", "sound": "default", "action": "SS" }
```

On iPhone/iPad/GalaxyTab/S3, when the push is received it plays the default alert sound and presents the notification on screen.

But for some reason the S4 does not display the push OR play a sound. I can only think of 2 explanations:

1) there is something wrong with the Parse code above

2) there is some setting on the S4 device that has disabled push notifications either for this app or completely

I am not an expert in either area (Parse or Android) so was hoping the community might know what I can do to troubleshoot further.

PS - first time StackOverflow poster. If my question doesn't meet the requirements of this forum I do apologise. Happy to schooled on how/when to use this forum!

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason why push is not displayed can be connected with customizing your push. Maybe try to modify your push data.

You put sound parameter and action parameter. Official Parse documentation says:

*alert: the notification's message.

*badge: (iOS only)

*sound: (iOS only)

*content-available: (iOS only)

*category: (iOS only)

*uri

*title: (Android, Windows 8, & Windows Phone 8 only)

Also go to applicaition list in setting in your phone and find your app.
There should be option: Notifications -> enabled.

Hope it will help.

Comment: Modify our push data to what exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Since it works on other android devices , i doubt it is your code that is causing the problem

It could be that your app is not allowed to show notifications , Check that "show notifications" is enabled in settings Settings->Apps->your_app .

Comment: Please check that in your installation class , there is a entry for your S4.

It could also not have arrived yet , sometimes push notifications from parse arrive late.

Comment: I checked the app settings and notifications are ticked to be received.

I will look into the Installations Class

Answer (score 0):

So you can try send this example push message:

```
JSONObject data = new JSONObject("{\"alert\": \"Message\",
                               \"title\": \"New push!\"}");

ParsePush push = new ParsePush();
push.setChannel("Mets");
push.setData(data);
push.sendPushInBackground();
```