# Parse Push Notification doesn't work on a specific android device

Tags: android, parsing, notifications

I used parse push notification and it works on several devices But not on one of those devices. Any idea?

the code:

```
 public class MyApplication extends android.app.Application {
   public MyApplication() {
   }

 @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

      Parse.initialize(this, "1Nfy7hle7....", "OX9CL7....");
     ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the notification subscribe for particular channel from which you want push notification.

```
ParsePush.subscribeInBackground("Your channel name",new SaveCallback() {
            @Override
            public void done(ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    Log.d("com.parse.push", "successfully subscribed to the broadcast channel.");
                } else {
                    Log.e("com.parse.push", "failed to subscribe for push", e);
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a duplicate question --> [Samsung Galaxy S4 Not Displaying Push Notifications from Parse.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28267533/samsung-galaxy-s4-not-displaying-push-notifications-from-parse-com)

Check whether you app is allowed to receive notifications, In setting->apps->your_app (check if the "show notifications " is checked)

Else

Check the Installation class , some times one of the fields does not get set like the device token , installation id.